# How do I get the haxe command back after installing Haxe 3

Tags: haxe

I installed Haxe 3 on os x using the manual install method on the following page http://haxe.org/manual/haxe3#manual_installation

Manual Installation

```
cp haxe /usr/bin/haxe
rm -rf /usr/lib/haxe
mkdir /usr/lib/haxe
cp -r std /usr/lib/haxe
mkdir /usr/lib/haxe/lib
chmod 777 /usr/lib/haxe/lib
cp std/tools/haxelib/haxelib.sh /usr/bin/haxelib
chmod +x /usr/bin/haxelib
```

After doing this if in a new terminal window I don't get the >haxe command. I just get command not found.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out all that was needed was to run the first cp command with sudo in front of it and all is well.

```
$> sudo cp haxe /usr/bin/haxe
```